# Processing a large (>32mb) xml file over appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to process large (~50mb) sized xml files to store in the datastore. I've tried using backends, sockets (to pull the file via urlfetch), and even straight up uploading the file within my source code, but again keep running into limits (i.e. the 32 mb limit).

So, I'm really confused (and a little angry/frustrated). Does appengine really have no real way to process a large file? There does seem to be one potential work around, which would involve remote_apis, amazon (or google compute I guess) and a security/setup nightmare...

Http ranges was another thing I considered, but it'll be painful to somehow connect the different splitted parts together (unless I can manage to split the file at exact points)

This seems crazy so I thought I'd ask stackover flow... am I missing something?

**update**
Tried using range requests and it looks like the server I'm trying to stream from doesn't use it. So right now I'm thinking either downloading the file, hosting it on another server, then use appengine to access that via range http requests on backends AND then automate the entire process so I can run it as a cron job :/ (the craziness of having to do all this work for something so simple... *sigh*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about storing it in the cloud storage and reading it incrementally, as you can access it line by line (in Python anyway) so it wont' consume all resources.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

https://developers.google.com/storage/

> The GCS client library lets your application read files from and write
>   files to buckets in Google Cloud Storage (GCS). This library supports
>   reading and writing large amounts of data to GCS, with internal error
>   handling and retries, so you don't have to write your own code to do
>   this. Moreover, it provides read buffering with prefetch so your app
>   can be more efficient.
>
> The GCS client library provides the following functionality:
>
> An open method that returns a file-like buffer on which you can invoke
>   standard Python file operations for reading and writing. A listbucket
>   method for listing the contents of a GCS bucket. A stat method for
>   obtaining metadata about a specific file. A delete method for deleting
>   files from GCS.

I've processed some very large CSV files in exactly this way - read as much as I need to, process, then read some more.

```
def read_file(self, filename):
    self.response.write('Truncated file content:\n')

    gcs_file = gcs.open(filename)
    self.response.write(gcs_file.readline())
    gcs_file.seek(-1024, os.SEEK_END)
    self.response.write(gcs_file.read())
    gcs_file.close()
```

Incremental reading with standard python!

Comment: Wow this could save me a ton of time, I'll try it right now Paul. Quick question for you, is it pretty easy to setup a cron job for Google Cloud Storage to urlfetch a file that's external, to update it on it's storage bin?

Comment: There's a JSON interface to it I believe which might help, but GCS is just a "bucket" for data so you can't set up a cron as such that it can run. I've used it by copying the file up "by hand" then accessing it from python/GAE, I've not "automated" that side of things I'm afraid.

Comment: Gotchya, and sorry just couple more questions, do you run the python code in backends? And how long can the GCS.open connection stay open? Does it have limits if I run on backends, and how do you start the next iteration where you left off? Thanks @Paul!

Comment: I was running it on a backend, but I guess you don't have to if you want to use chained tasks or similar (tasks that call the next task when complete). As far as I know, the connection just stays open until closed. As to iteration, well, I've just read line by line one after the other until the file was empty. but I guess you'd store where you "got" too and seek to that position next time you get some data.