# Using backends and google cloud store to efficiently process large data files

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

This is a follow up on my question regarding [processing large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124335/processing-a-large-32mb-xml-file-over-appengine/20125307?noredirect=1#comment29993623_20125307) using google app engine. The solution was Google Cloud Storage and I've spent the whole day wrestling with it and have run into some big issues.

The backend I'm using is a B4_1G. And I'm trying to process a 55mb sized xml file. The code currently is pretty basic, I'm just trying to make sure I can simply print out the file to a user before I start doing anything fancy with it:

```
gcs_file = gcs.open(filename)
gcs_file.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
for line in gcs_file:
    self.response.write(line)
gcs_file.close()
```

The result is that the backend simply crashes. On the browser it spits out "Uncaught application failure" (even though it's nestled in a try, except statement). On my logs it says:

```
"The process handling this request unexpectedly died. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application."
```

I've tested this code with a tiny hello world text file and it works. So my guess is that as a beginner I'm doing something so inefficient that it's causing the server to crash after a few minutes. I have considered chaining tasks to do it, but I really would prefer not to write all that extra code... there must be a way to do it in backends right?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this. I might guess that perhaps your filename is wrong and gcs_file is not defined. Or possibly the first line of the file is VERY long, perhaps 55 megs all on one line. Also maybe try removing the seek() call and see if that helps. Please report back if you figure it out!

Comment: Hey Brandon, I've tested the filename, by just doing one readline (outside the loop) and it works fine.

Comment: Also got rid of the seek() call and inspected the file. The seek call didn't help and the file has fairly short lines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around it a ton, it turns out the self.response.write was the problem. My guess is, printing out 55mb messed the whole thing up. Once I removed that and added my processing code, I noticed that everything was working fine :).

Comment: Ah, of course! The response size of App Engine requests must not exceed 32 megabytes, or Google will cut you off. This would have worked with a 30 megabyte file. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/?csw=1#Quotas_and_Limits